# Chamfer middle of menu

Tags: html, css

I try to chamfer the middle of the menu but I can't find how to do it in CSS.

Here is what I would like :

[image]

Didn't found a good way to do it.
Tried with some pseudo elements and bottom-left & bottom-right radius.

I could take the logo with the bottom things I guess, but I'm pretty sure it's possible to do it CSS way, but I can't find how.

Here is how I structured it :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.header>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 90px;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "left center right";
}

.header ul.menu>li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.header li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__left {
  grid-area: left;
  justify-self: right;
}

.header__center {
  grid-area: center;
}

.header__right {
  grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__left">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header__center">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="header__right">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong with your attempt at using pseudo-elements, but this seems to work. You might need to fiddle with margins, padding, and position a bit.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1600);
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: pink;
}

ul,
li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header {
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header .container {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: -35px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header>div {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 90px;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "left center right";
}

.header ul.menu>li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.header li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header__left {
    grid-area: left;
    justify-self: right;
}

.header__center {
    grid-area: center;
}

.header__right {
    grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__left">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="header__center">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
        </div>
        <div class="header__right">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pt34udvg/)**